Identifying Kafka consumer has been removed from a consumer group
I'm using Spring Kafka for producing to a Kafka topic and consuming from it.
Everything works fine and as expected.
A consumer is considered alive as long as it sends heartbeats at regular intervals using heartbeat.interval.ms; once heartbeats are no longer sent for the period determined by session.timeout.ms the group coordinator will consider it DEAD and trigger a rebalance.
I would like to identify the case where my consumer - for some reason - has gone dead and removed from the group.
Notes:

The process in which the dead consumer used to run is still up & running.
I would like to identify above case so I'll know I need to bring it back (i.e. re-subscribe to the related topic).

I'm familiar with the AdminClient with which I can describe the cluster and get a list of all consumers under a specific topic.
Is there another way or a better way to identify above situation?
For example, when I initially subscribe to a topic is there a way to register my consumer to some event listener from which I will get a notification once my consumer has been removed from the group?

Let's see if NonResponsiveConsumerEvent meets your requirements: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/events.html#idle-containers !

@ArtemBilan Given the condition I mentioned in my initial post - i.e. a consumer is considered alive as long as it sends heartbeats at regular intervals using heartbeat.interval.ms; once heartbeats are no longer sent for the period determined by session.timeout.ms the group coordinator will consider it DEAD and trigger a rebalance after removing this consumer from the consumer group - if this condition is fulfilled, does it mean that the related KafkaMessageListenerContainer instance has stopped or is it still alive and might be "awake" again at some point and rejoin the group?

@ArtemBilan In other words, I'm trying to understand if there is some relationship between the fact that a consumer was removed from its group to the liveliness of its related container?

No, it is not stopped. It is just removed from the group by coordinator for that session timeout reason. This consumer indeed can rejoin the group in the future.

@ArtemBilan Regarding rejoin: If, for example, the processing of a record in a KafkaMessageListenerContainer instance takes too long which eventually leads to removal of related consumer from the consumer group and to a rebalance by the group coordinator, then would rejoin attempt(s) will be done automatically by the container or is it an action we need to initiate programmatically?

It has to happen automatically since we don't leave the mail loop where we call KafkaConsumer.poll().

@ArtemBilan One last question: since heartbeats are being sent in a separate thread then the main processing thread (during which the poll is called & actual job is being processed), are there any other reasons for the heartbeats not arriving to the broker aside these 3 ones? 1) Network failure 2) LeaveGroup request issued by the heartbeat thread when max.poll.interval.ms has been exceeded between polls 3) Consumer application being shut down.
